# closest facility analysis arcpy

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, error-000732, closest-facility

The following picture shows the location of the files I need for the Closest Facility Analysis.
[image]

What's wrong with my code?

```
import arcpy


arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\test\2.gdb"
inNetworkDataset = "C:\Users\TL\Desktop\test\2.gdb\network\network_ND"
inIncidents = r'G_Fac'
inFacilities = r'HighwayJunctions'
outGeodatabase = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\test\2.gdb"
outRoutes = "Routes"
outDirections = "Directions"
outClosestFacilities = "ClosestFacilities"
measurement_units = "Feet"

# Run FindClosestFacilities. Choose to find only the closest facility.
arcpy.na.FindClosestFacilities(inIncidents, inFacilities, measurement_units,
                                    inNetworkDataset, outGeodatabase, outRoutes,
                                    outDirections, outClosestFacilities,
                                    Number_of_Facilities_to_Find=1)

print "Script completed successfully"
```

The error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\na.py", line 2630, in FindClosestFacilities
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Network Dataset: Dataset C:\Users\TL\Desktop  est.gdb
etwork
etwork_ND does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (FindClosestFacilities).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really say: "C:\Users\TL\Desktop est.gdb"?

You might need to put an r in front on the " in inNetworkDatset.

```
inNetworkDataset = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\test\2.gdb\network\network_ND"
```

Slashes are escape characters.

Another option would be to reverse the \ to /:

```
"C:/Users/TL/Desktop/test/2.gdb/network/network_ND"
```

Comment: You are right. Also, I add a field for time measurement and the code works.